# Add Module from GIT to Android Studio throws "buildToolsVersion is not specified" error

Tags: java, android, git, gradle

I want to include [this Color Picker](http://www.materialdoc.com/color-picker/) into my Android Studio project.

So I checked it out into a local folder, added it to my project with the "New->Import Module Dialog in Android Studio.

Then I added those 2 lines to my app.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...
compile project(':colorpicker')
```

Here is the complete gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mydomain.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile fileTree(include: ['dtp_library'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':libs:dtp_library')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'        
    compile project(':colorpicker')
}
```

But I keep getting the error

> Error:Cause: buildToolsVersion is not specified.

If I do not add the first line to the gradle file (do it exactly like the color picker description said) then I get

> Error:(3, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_xxxxx] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

How to fix it?

Comment: I will try this and let u know although u can also create this with gridview and fab buttons

Comment: dude check out the solution , it's done

Answer (score 9):

Follow the steps :

Open the `build.gradle` file of color picker module

[image]

so in your case add these lines to `build.gradle` file of `colorpicker` module

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'
```

Comment: I tried to add the buildToolsVersion. I went into that project folder, added it to the gradle file. But I get still the same error. Do I have to refresh this somehow. I did change it externally.

Comment: The second option throws the second error mentioned in my question.

Comment: @juergend try updated part with allprojects  and compile dependency

Comment: And removing `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` makes the app not having even a main module and is not runnable any more. And `compile 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.12'` is another color picker.

Comment: I already tried that too. Now I ended up including the code directly into my project and it works. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @juergend oh but it worked on mine , i just download the module , then add it from file=>add new module and didn't select anything except no and added these two lines and it worked(as in pic ) but anyway you achieved what was desired , great

Answer (score -1):

Please put your buildToolVersion in double quotes like

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

Comment: That changes nothing.